# Compare values in SQL using CASE, if match return and exit from CASE statement

Tags: sql

Person table:

```
PersonID    Name
       1    David
       2    Victor
```

Phone Number table:

```
PersonID    Phonetype   PhoneNumber
       1            7   7735821547
       1            6   7731245263
       1            5   7731426587
       1            4   7731243654
       1            8   7731241478
       1            2   7731423658
       1            1   7731427485
       2            1   7731547841
```

Priority to pull number by phonetype: 4 then 6 then 7 then 5 then 8 then 2 then 1

I want to pull phone number for each person but when i use left join then it returns multiple columns. I only want one number for each person.

Outputs should be:

```
PersonID    Name    PhoneNumber
       1    David   7731243654
       2    Victor  7731547841
```

Comment: use a different number in `THEN` in that case

Comment: That is how `case` statements work.

Comment: Is that just a part of a statement, or standalone? Which dbms?

Comment: Case statements never return anything, it's just conditional code (like if). A case expression returns a value, the one for the first found true WHEN.

Comment: Why do you define a condition that is invalid? If you don't want that `PhoneType = 6` will be 1 then don't specify that.

Comment: Can you specify what your expected output should be? It is now very hard to answer your question.

Comment: You can use a case statement within a case statement

Comment: On person has multiple phone numbers linked to their Person_ID. I only want to return one phone number. That's why i am using Phonetype to get only one phonenumber.

Comment: I want to set up the priority by phonetype. If phonetype=7 then it should pick that phonenumber first then exit. if Phonenumber=7 and Phonenumber is null then check second condition phone number=6 then return value.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your data?

Comment: Hi Juan, I updated an question with expected output.

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: You should really explain better what you exactly want.

Comment: From what I can tell, they want to select the value of PhoneNbr where it isn't null in the order 7,6,1,2,3,4,5,8,9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use postgres for this example, I use row_number() and cte, if you have mySql will need a workaorund

You need a table priority

```
CREATE TABLE priority
    ("PhoneType" int, "Priority" int)
;

INSERT INTO priority
    ("PhoneType", "Priority")
VALUES
    (7, 1),        (6, 2),
    (1, 3),        (2, 4),
    (3, 5),        (4, 6),
    (5, 7),        (8, 8),
    (9, 9)    ;
```

Then put a `rownumber` to each phonetype acording to priority

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT 
          p.*,
          pr."Priority",
          row_number() over (partition by "PersonID" ORDER BY "Priority") as rn
    FROM person p
    JOIN priority pr
      ON p."PhoneType" = pr."PhoneType"
    ORDER BY pr."Priority"
)
SELECT 
    c."PersonID",
    c."PhoneType", 
    c."PhoneNumber",
    CASE rn 
       WHEN 1 THEN 1
       ELSE NULL
    END as rn
FROM cte c
```

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f1f1a/1)**

**OUTPUT**

```
| PersonID | PhoneType | PhoneNumber |     rn |
|----------|-----------|-------------|--------|
|        1 |         7 |  7735487695 |      1 |
|        1 |         1 |  7731234569 | (null) |
|        1 |         5 |  7731547895 | (null) |
```

NOTE: I also change type `6 => 5` in your sample to highlight even more how the priority is working

After your edit **[SQL Server verion without table Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09ec48/3)**

```
With Priority as (
    SELECT 7 as PhoneType,  1 as Priority UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 as PhoneType,  2 as Priority UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 as PhoneType,  3 as Priority UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as PhoneType,  4 as Priority UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 as PhoneType,  5 as Priority UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 as PhoneType,  6 as Priority UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 as PhoneType,  7 as Priority UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 as PhoneType,  8 as Priority UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 as PhoneType,  9 as Priority 
), 
cte as (
    SELECT 
          p.*,
          pr.Priority,
          row_number() over (partition by PersonID ORDER BY Priority) as rn
    FROM Person p
    JOIN Priority pr
      ON p.PhoneType = pr.PhoneType    
)
SELECT 
    c.PersonID,
    c.PhoneType, 
    c.PhoneNumber
FROM cte c
WHERE rn = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| PersonID | PhoneType | PhoneNumber |
|----------|-----------|-------------|
|        1 |         7 |  7735821547 |
|        2 |         1 |  7731547841 |
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without creating table?

Comment: Check my edit with sql 2012 version and creating a virtual table with a cte

Answer (score 0):

You have too many WHEN statements. If you only want to do something for value 7 you should only have one WHEN statement:

```
CASE 
WHEN PhoneType = 7 and PhoneNbr is not null THEN 1 
ELSE NULL
END AS RN
```

Comment: I want to pull phone number if phonetype=6. But your answer will only return 7 or NULL value

Comment: @vinus patel: Which is exactly what you were asking. You should have accepted this answer, because it matches the expected results you showed. Now you have altered your whole question completely. I suggest: delete this question and ask anew, because the answers given match the original question naturally.

Comment: I can not delete this question.